# sum of multiplications of number sets with sum n

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

suppose $n$ , $k$ are positive integers both. if for any set $ \{ a_1,a_2,....,a_k \}$ with sum of $n$ we write down multiplication of $a_1,a_2,....,a_k$.
now I want to prove that the sum of written numbers is $\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}$ .